# Fade in text over an image

Tags: jquery, css

Two things don't seem to work with [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/r7Acy/).

1. I want to be able to hover the larger DIV in order to bring the smaller one into view.

As it stands, it only works if you hover over the smaller DIV.
2. The smaller DIV doesn't disappear when I stop hovering.

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>

<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

```
.one {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #333;
}
```

```
/* Fade-in text over images */
$(function(){
    $(".two").css("opacity",0).fadeTo(0, 0);
    $(".two").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
    });
    $("two").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(200, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the badly formatted post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are selecting *smaller* div tags.

```
$(function() {
    $(".two").hide();
    $(".one").hover(function() {
        $('.two', this).fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
        $('.two', this).fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7Acy/7/)

- [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)
- [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Answer (score 3):

You should target the larger div, `.one`, and then change the smaller div, `.two` within the context of `this` whenever hovering `.one`. When fading from visible to invisble you can most of the time use fadeIn/Out, and just set the element to `display:none` in the CSS.

```
$(function(){
    $('.one').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(".two", this).fadeIn(200);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(".two", this).fadeOut(200);        
        }
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7Acy/5/)

Answer (score 3):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7Acy/8/)*

```
$(".one").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function ( e ) {
      var fade = e.type=='mouseenter'?
      $('.two', this).stop().fadeTo(200, 1):
      $('.two', this).stop().fadeTo(200, 0);
});
```